# Fixing my background image and website layout on Blogger using CSS or HTML

Tags: html, css, image, background, blogger

Heres my website: www.ChrisStephensMusic.net

As you can see the background image is not full size and moves when the page is scrolled. I'd like it to be full size and remain still while the content scrolls. I've tried the CSS suggestions I could find when searching this topic here but they do nothing when I add them to the "Custom CSS" on Blogger. Is there a better way to fix this using HTML or is there something else I need to do to get the custom CSS to be recognized?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code in your css file for the background image:

```
    width: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
```

Answer (score 0):

**CSS**

```
html { 
  background: url(image.png) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

source: https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Answer (score 0):

Add the following CSS -

```
.bg-photo-container, div.bg-photo-overlay {
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
}
```

The custom CSS option is not working because some invalid rules have been added to it, which is causing every rule after that to be ignored. I would instead suggest, adding this via HTML/JavaScript gadget by wrapping the code in a `style` tag so that it looks like

```
<style>
  .bg-photo-container, div.bg-photo-overlay {
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
  }
</style>
```

The final result should look like -

[image]

Comment: Yes! This is what I want it to do! Thank you for the .GIF and the codes. I'll try asap. The background still isn't full size in what you posted, but I'll try the other suggestions. Where should I put that HTML?